# Sum of column by groupBy in Eloquent

Tags: eloquent

My database has a record for each of our engineers weekly hours.  What I need to do return all the hours for a period ('period_id'),  group them by engineer ('engineer_id'), and then sum each of the following cols mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, and sun.  Basically returning the total hours for each engineer for a period.

[image]

Hope this makes sense.
Got this far.

```
$totals = Hours::where('late', 0)->where('period_id', $period->id);
$hours_totals = $totals->groupBy('employee_id');
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide some sample data, and maybe the raw SQL query you are trying to do from Eloquent.  Currently, you're calling `get()` in the first line, and AFAIK that will close the result set.

Comment: Will add some data

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```php
Hours::select('engineer_id', DB::raw('sum(mon) mon'), DB::raw('sum(tues) tues'), [...])
    ->where('late', 0)
    ->where('period_id', 1)
    ->groupBy('engineer_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?